# receiving 401 errors inconsistently from python urllib2.urlopen call

Tags: python, urllib2

I have a python script that makes a series of url calls using urllib2.  The url is on http, but requires authentication.  I am currently trying to run the script such that it will make over 100 calls.  Every time I run the script, some calls fail with error code 401, and some pass.  All calls are for the same URL using the same username and password.  (Each time I run the script it is not the same calls that fail, sometimes the first call fails, sometimes it works.)

Any ideas why a 401 might occur inconsistently?

The error message printed to the screen is...

Here is the method responsible for making the url call:

```
def simpleExecuteRequest(minX, minY, maxX, maxY, type) :
    url = 'http://myhost.com/geowebcache/rest/seed/mylayer.xml'

    msgTemplate = """<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
    <seedRequest>
    <name>mylayer</name>
    <bounds>
    <coords>
    <double>%s</double>
    <double>%s</double>
    <double>%s</double>
    <double>%s</double>
    </coords>
    </bounds>
    <gridSetId>nyc</gridSetId>
    <zoomStart>0</zoomStart>
    <zoomStop>10</zoomStop>
    <format>image/png</format>
    <type>%s</type>
    <threadCount>1</threadCount>
    </seedRequest>
    """

    message = msgTemplate%(minX, minY, maxX, maxY, type)
    headers = { 'User-Agent' : "Python script", 'Content-type' : 'text/xml; charset="UTF-8"', 'Content-length': '%d' % len(message) }
    passwordManager = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
    passwordManager.add_password(None, url, 'username', 'xxx')
    authenticationHandler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passwordManager)
    proxyHandler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({})
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxyHandler, authenticationHandler)
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)    

    try :
        request = urllib2.Request(url, message, headers)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
        content = response.read()
        print 'success'
    except IOError, e:
        print e
```

Sometimes the output will look like this...

```
<urlopen error (10053, 'Software caused connection abort')>
success
success
<urlopen error (10053, 'Software caused connection abort')>
<urlopen error (10053, 'Software caused connection abort')>
...
```

When run 1 minute later it might look like this...

```
success
<urlopen error (10053, 'Software caused connection abort')>
success
success
<urlopen error (10053, 'Software caused connection abort')>
```

On both runs the same series of inputs for min/max x/y and type were provided in the same order.
    ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks correct to me, so I don't see the issue.

Here are a few thoughts on how to proceed:

- I usually work-out the http requests at the command line using `curl` before translating it into a script.
- The [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) library is easier to use than urllib2
- When you receive a response, print out the headers so you can see what is going on
- Instead of `except IOError, e` use `except IOError as e`.  The new way protects you from hard to find errors.
- I presume you redacted the username and password and are using the real ones in your own script ;-)

Comment: At this point I also agree that the code is not the issue.  I added retry and wait logic into the script.  If I sleep 5 seconds between failed attempts and retry up to 10 times I can get all 119 requests to execute successfully in a single script execution.  Some took up to 8 attempts, some succeeded on the first attempt.  Not pretty, but it gets the job done since this is just a one-off script.